# haystack autocomplete jquery ui not being able to make it works

Tags: jquery, django, jquery-ui, autocomplete, django-haystack

I'm trying to pass data generated as a list by my custom view:

```
def autocomplete(request):
sqs = SearchQuerySet().autocomplete(content_auto=request.GET.get('q', ''))[$
suggestions = [result.name_esp for result in sqs]
return HttpResponse(suggestions)
```

But I don't know how to define "suggestions" in the script area to be the source for the jquery ui. I can only find examples where jquery ui is using an already defined list, like [here](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/)

Comment: You can take a look at a similar JSON example in my answer here: stackoverflow.com/questions/19662956

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The jQuery page you link to has several examples of using an Ajax request as the source: click  "Remote datasource" on the right-hand side and then "view source" at the bottom to see the code. It looks like all you need to do is add a `source` element to your `autocomplete` function, whose value is the URL that returns your data.

As well as that, though, you'll need to be sure that the data is in the right format: that means serializing it to JSON:

```
return HttpResponse(json.dumps(suggestions))
```

Comment: Many thanks Daniel for your response, I have been analyzing several examples and I think I'm almost there. So, following your jsn return, shall I create the ajax request with source: json.dumps(suggestions) and data: json ??

Comment: No, you're mixing up what goes where. `source` is the URL that your Django autocomplete view is being served on. The `json.dumps` bit goes in that Python view, in place of your current return statement.

Comment: Umm... so, if the view ("autocomplete" in this case) is called by: url(r'^$', views.autocomplete, name='autocomplete'), I have to include: source : http://127.0.0.1/ (if I'm running the aplication locally)?

Comment: Yes (although the value needs to be in quotes). Or you could just do `source: '/'`, since the current page is presumably on the same server, so you just need to provide a relative address.

Answer (score -1):

You need to make a request for you back-end, like this:

```
$(function() {
    var availableTags = [];

    $.get( "YOUR BACK-END HERE", function( data ) {
        availableTags  = data;
    });

    $( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
        source: availableTags
    });
});
```

I didn't tested this.